# error in for statment with html helpers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I use the following code and I got error

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <tr>
       if (Model[i].Id == ViewBag.SelectedID)
       {
           <td>
               @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].name)
           </td>
           <td>
               @Html.EditorFor(m=> m[i]checkBox1)
           </td>
           ............
       }
    </tr>
}
```

The error is in

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].name)
```

and

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=> m[i]checkBox1)
```

**The error is**

`try specifying the arguments explicitly`. What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**

I try also the following but I got error in the check boxes,how to solve it?

```
  @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (item.Id == ViewBag.SelectedID)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBox(item.name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(item.checkBox1)
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save">Save</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </td>
                }
```

The error in:
@Html.EditorFor(item.checkBox1)

I tried to change it to @Html.TextBox(item.checkBox1) or @Html.CheckBoxFor(item.checkBox1)
and the error is remain,any idea how to manage it?

Comment: What error do you get? Can you show us your model too?

Comment: @hi patrick the model is very simple it contain only property name and checkBox1,the error is in the view in compile time so im not sure how to copy it,any idea?

Comment: what is "m"? shouldn't it be "Model" which is the actual Model being given to the View itself for you to use?

Comment: @Ahmedilyas-even when I change it to model I got the same error...any idea?

Comment: Actually you want to show CheckBox or TextBox for property item.checkBox1 ,first confirm that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using For loop just try foreach and display each items.

For Eg :

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
 {
  <tr>
   <td>
     @Html.TextBox(item.name)
   </td>
  </tr>
}
```

**EDIT**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                @if (item.Id == ViewBag.SelectedID)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.TextBox(item.name)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBox(item.checkBox1)
                    </td>


                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="save">Save</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
                    </td>
                }
```

Comment: @mileyH: You can check specific item by  "if (item.Id == ViewBag.SelectedID)" this condition

Comment: Thanks,do you have idea why im getting error for  @Html.CheckBoxFor(item.checkBox1),I have this property in the model ...

Comment: You can use "@Html.CheckBox(item.checkBox1)". If your using "@Html.CheckBoxFor(item.checkBox1)" that uses strongly typed Lambda Expressions.But here we are not directly using it.

Comment: Thanks but tried also this and I got the same error,any idea?at least how to copy the error?since I see red line under the command and just when I hoover over it I see the error message...

Comment: @mileyH: Can you please update error details or your code here.

Comment: Actually you want to show CheckBox or TextBox for property item.checkBox1 ,first confirm that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54990/discussion-between-vyas-and-mileyh).

Comment: try to use simple html input box                                  <input name=" @(item.Id)" type="checkbox" value="@(item.checkBox1)" id=" @(item.Id)"  />